# Reusing async function in react native

Tags: react-native

I am building a page to fetch data from API when loaded, but encounter waring `an effect function must not return anything besides a function which is used for clean-up` when trying to reuse the function for fetching data

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
    // this way does not work as I expected, my page does not show data I fetched
    const getData = async () => {
        const result = await dispatch(actions.getList())；
        setState(result);
    };
    getData();
},[isFirstLoaded]);
```

But I get the warning when trying below

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const getData = async () => {
    const result = await dispatch(actions.getList());
    setState(result);
};

useEffect(async() => {
    // this way gives me the data but with a warning
    await getData();
},[isFirstLoaded]);
```

How should I reuse the `getData` function? I did not update the state if I am not using the `async` and `await` here. When I use `async` and `await` here, I get the warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

overall, you are heading in the right direction. For fetching data, you'd wanna use use Effect and pass [] as a second argument to make sure it fires only on initial mount.

I believe you could benefit from decoupling fetching function and making it more generic, as such:

```
const fetchJson = async (url) => {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json();
};

const Fetch = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJson("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then(({ disclaimer }) => setData(disclaimer));
  }, []);

  return <Text>{data}</Text>;
};
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answer with an explanation are usually of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.